# Hatcher K-Theory continuity of $\alpha \to \inf_{(x,z)\in X \times S^1} \det|\alpha(x,z)|$

Tags: continuity, compactness, supremum-and-infimum, vector-bundles, topological-k-theory

Does [Hatcher](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf) makes an error at page $45$ afirming that $f:\alpha \mapsto \inf_{(x,z)\in X \times S^1} \det|\alpha(x,z)|$ is continuous? I didn't find any reference of continuity of $\inf$ of continuous functions on a compact set. It seems to me that lower semicontinuity of $f$ is enough to affirm that $f^{-1}(0,+\infty) = \operatorname{Aut}(E\times S^1)$ is open, what am I missing?

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: You should define the notations! What is $X$? What is $E$? Anyway, on a compact space $T$, $f \in C(T,\mathbb{R}) \longmapsto \inf_T{f}$ is $1$-Lipschitz and therefore continuous.

Comment: @jacopoburelli you are not missing anything